# MSI only deployment solution for vsto word addin

Tags: c#, deployment, wix, windows-installer, vsto

there are a lot of ways to deploy Microsoft Word AddIn, the [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) is a pretty good start. but the problem for me is that by the end of the steps described in the tutorial I will get a Setup.exe.
what I need is an MSI installer for my add-in. I try to accomplish this task using [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/), but there are some prerequestis(*Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime for exampl*e) for  AddIn and to install them you need to create bootstrapper project which is also an Exe installer. So my question is: is there a way to deploy the Word add-in using MSI installer only?

UPDATE:
the question is marked as duplicate, but in that question, there is no answer to my exact question. there is no description how to create single MSI (InstallShield  creates separate MSI database, separate setup.exe, and separate prerequisites.) and that question is not Wix related

Comment: Why do you need an MSI installer?

Comment: Because ClickOnce sucks, especially in distributed environments. @MickyD

Comment: customer request.

Comment: @PatrickHofman ewww yes agree with you there.  I didnt realise it was using that tech